# Add mean line to ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I currently have this plot:

[current plot without mean line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCzO8.png)

I want to add a continuous line in the plot that shows the mean value of each x-axis point.
How can i do this? Here is my code:

```
data <- ndpdata[which(ndpdata$FC.Fill.Size==250),] #250 fill size
data$PS_DATE <- as.Date(data$PS_DATE,  "%Y-%m-%d")
data$PS_DATE <- as.Date(data$PS_DATE,  "%m-%d-%Y")
data$final <- paste(data$PS_DATE, data$FC.Batch.Nbr, sep="       ") %>% na.omit()

library(tidyr)
my_df_long <- gather(data, group, y, -final)
data = my_df_long[2075:2550,] %>% na.omit()


 ggplot(data, aes(final, y, color=final), na.rm=TRUE) + 
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5)) + theme(legend.position = "none") + geom_point(na.rm=TRUE) +
   scale_y_discrete(breaks = c(251,270,290,310,325))
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, for the future please note the note of MrFlick.

We could use `stat_summary`. `x` should be factor and in a meaningful order.
I can't test because no data provided:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(final), y, color=final), na.rm=TRUE) + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5)) + theme(legend.position = "none") + geom_point(na.rm=TRUE) +
    scale_y_discrete(breaks = c(251,270,290,310,325)) +
    stat_summary(fun=mean, colour="red", geom="line", aes(group = 1))
```