# Adding a line with the mean value of plotted points in ggplot with facet wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am working with a dataframe that has centre wise sales made by each person on different dates. Sample data can be generated as follows

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(
  centre = rep(c('A', 'B'), 4),
  person = c('p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6', 'p7', 'p8')
) %>%
  full_join(
    tibble(date = seq(as.Date('2022-01-01'), as.Date('2022-01-5'), 1)),
    by = character()
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    num = round(runif(nrow(.), min = 50, max = 100),0)
  ) ->
  df
```

I am trying to plot the sales vs date trend for different people as follows

```
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  group_by(centre, person) %>%
  mutate(mean_num = mean(num, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = num)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~person, scales = 'free') +
  xlab('Date') +
  ylab('Sales') +
  ggtitle('Sales vs Date') ->
  plt
```

I want to add to each facet the mean of values in that facet (that is the mean of sales made by each person). I have tried three methods, but none of them seem to work. Method 3 from the following link [Add mean line to ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68534470/add-mean-line-to-ggplot)

```
# Method 1
plt +
geom_hline(yintercept = mean(num), linetype = 'dotted', colour = 'red')

# Method 2
plt +
geom_hline(yintercept = mean_num, linetype = 'dotted', colour = 'red')

# Method 3
plt +
stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = 'line', colour = 'red')
```

I can make a separate dataframe for means and then use that to plot, but wanted to do it in one pipeline. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `yintercept` as an aesthetic mapping:

```r
plt +
geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean_num), linetype = 'dotted', colour = 'red')
```

The code you currently have is looking for a single value for `mean_num` in the global environment. By passing `aes(yintercept = mean_num)` to the `mapping` argument of `geom_hline`, you make it clear to ggplot that you want to use the variable from `df` and map it to each facet separately.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work. Though I am not clear on why we need to pass the yintercept as an aesthetic? Could you point me to a source where I can understand more?

Comment: This might be a good place to start:  https://ggplot2-book.org/mastery.html#mapping-aesthetics-to-data

Comment: The gist is that if you can assign values, or you can map them to your data. So `aes(colour = caterpillar_size)` will create a colour scale based on `caterpillar_size` in the data, whereas `fill = "red"` will just colour everything red (which needs to reference to data columns)